# How to run a cron job to execute every minute?

Tags: rhel, cron

I am trying to create a directory having a timestamp in its in name in the `/home` directory. I have created the following cron job as the root user, but it's not running. What am I doing wrong?

Following is my cron job which I have created with root user privilege.

```
[root@bvdv-emmws01 home]# crontab -l
* * * * * /home/test.sh
```

Following are the contents of `/home/test.sh`.
**Update:** added full path for directory.

```
[root@bvdv-emmws01 home]# cat /home/test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /home/test_$(date -d "today" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

Permission of `/home/test.sh`:

```
[root@bvdv-emmws01 home]# ls -ltr /home/test.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 Dec  2 12:58 /home/test.sh
```

I have updated the `/etc/crontab` file. That file now has the following contents:

```
[root@bvdv-emmws01 home]# cat /etc/crontab
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed

* * * * * root /home/test.sh
```

Status of `crond daemon`

```
[root@bvdv-emmws01 home]# service crond status
crond (pid  1910) is running...
```

Comment: Does it work when you execute `/home/test.sh` in a shell? What is the output of `ls -l /home/test.sh`?

Comment: You might want to use absolute paths in your script as well.

Comment: `[root@bvdv-emmws01 home]# ls -l test.sh `
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 Dec  2 12:58 test.sh`

Comment: @HaukeLaging when I run it through shell, it do create directory with name like test_00000000

Comment: Those directories will be created in the home directory of the user (here `root` so something like `/` or `/root`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That was the main catch. After these changes, it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A crontab created with `crontab -e` and listable with `crontab -l` should not have a user specified for the command. Your entry should read:

```
* * * * * /home/test.sh
```

Or alternatively put the line that you have in `/etc/crontab` instead.

From `man 5 crontab` (section EXAMPLE SYSTEM CRON FILE):

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.
```

Note the last sentence.

Comment: I have added `* * * * * root /home/test.sh` in my `/etc/crontab`. But still no luck. Unable to see directory in my `/home`.

Comment: @TahirAkram can you do a `cat /home/test.sh` instead of `cat test.sh` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: Is crond deamon running?

Comment: Does test.sh have the executable permissions set?

Comment: @Albert `[root@bvdv-emmws01 home]# service crond status`
`crond (pid  1910) is running...` Yes it's running.

Comment: @Anthon I have updated question description with permissions of /home/test.sh and it's cat output.

Comment: @YoMismo I have updated question description with the permission of /home/test.sh.

Comment: @ALL after changing putting full path in test.sh it starts creating directories in /home. It works. Question is answered.